# 'var' is null on at least one execution path - sonarqube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, nullreferenceexception

using sonarqube to analyze my code and being told "'actor' is null on at least one execution path" for the following code

```
if (actor.ProducerAgreementIds != null && actor.ProducerAgreementIds.Count > 0)
   {
```

`actor.ProducerAgreementIds` is a `List<string>`.

isn't this statement already performing a null check? or should it instead be:

```
if (actor != null && (actor.ProducerAgreementIds != null && actor.ProducerAgreementIds.Count > 0))
    {
```

alternative would just using conditional access

`if (actor?.ProducerAgreementIds != null && actor.ProducerAgreementIds.Count > 0)`

be appropriate and not cause downstream issues?

thanks!

Comment: Can you post your whole code? It's hard to make it out, when you're just posting snippets out-of-order.

Comment: It might be a problem with multi-threading. This will do too btw: `if (actor?.ProducerAgreementIds?.Count > 0)`.

Comment: A short way of writing this would be:
if (prs?.Any() ?? false)

Comment: I don't see the code which tests for `actor != null` in the code in your edit - please include that in your "whole code"

Comment: Right, so we can't tell the relationship between the `actor != null` check, and the line on which the warning is raised. So we can't tell whether the warning is right or not. That means that we can't answer your question - there isn't enough information. Voting to close. I recommend coming up with a [mcve] which still reproduces the issue (remove some of those 508 lines, without affecting the warning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this validation it would be sufficient:

```
 if (actor?.ProducerAgreementIds?.Count > 0)
 {
 }
```

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: @PatrickHofman When it finds a null value, it does not continue to evaluate the following conditions

Comment: @asd - Edit your answer to include the detail s in your comment?